# The name of the X-terminal joke with the dinosaur kicking windows?

Tags: x11, games

In the computer room at our local college we only had X-terminals, somewhere in the 90's. We played tricks on other people's screen, by sending X-output to their screen if they forgot to close it with "xhost -".

One of the tricks was a dinosaur walking around on the screen, stomping on the victim's windows and kicking them away.

What was the name of that program?